# How to selectively sync using sshfs?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, remote-server, sshfs

Original question: Let's say I have a remote folder with .R, .py and .pkl files. How to avoid syncing .pkl files or how to sync .R files only? How to avoid syncing specific sub-folders?

Sorry I was wrong on my understanding. sshfs is not a sync utility but is a software to mount a remote system to a local folder accessible via SSH.

I am not deleting this question so that it helps the future readers.

Now, my next question would be: how to selectively block sub-folders in the remote folder from being shown in the local folder? how to selectively block sub-folders in the local folder from being updated in the remote folder?

Comment: sshfs is not doing **any** sync.

Answer (score 2):

You can mount with [--bind](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) option needed directories. Mount will exclude them from sshfs.
\For example if you have mounted dir in `/var/www/site`/ via

`sshfs /var/www/site`

Then you can mount the cache dir locally

```
mount /var/www/site/cache /tmp/site1cahe --bind
```

And cache will be local-only :)